# "appendTo"-method not functioning correctly when connecting a draggable to a sortable element in jQueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to connect a jQueryUI draggable element to a sortable element with the helper always appended to the body. When I drag the draggable element over to the sortable element, the helper gets inserted at the sortable element. Eventhough the sortable elements all append to the body element on drag.

```
$(".a").sortable({
    appendTo: document.body,
    connectWith: ".a",
    helper: "clone"
}).disableSelection();

$("section div").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".a",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    appendTo: document.body
}).parent().disableSelection();
```

To demonstrate my problem, I made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fnmfndby/

As you can see when dragging an sortable element the helper is green. When dragging the draggable element it is also green, but when dragging it over the sortable it turns red.

Regards,
Ties

Comment: Jump to [line 6615 here](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js): it has `ui.helper.appendTo(sortable.element)`, so this behaviour is by design. If you fiddle with it enough, you can probably manually get at the behaviour you want, but there's no out-of-the-box solution, so I wouldn't expect easy forward-compatibility. [(Or you could submit it as a bug report...)](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by converting the draggable item to a sortable item and with the sortable-api make it act like a draggable item.

```
$(".a").sortable({
    appendTo: document.body,
    connectWith: ".a",
    helper: "clone"
}).disableSelection();

$("section").sortable({
    connectWith: ".a",
    appendTo: document.body,
    helper: "clone",
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        return false;
    },
    stop: function (event,ui) {
        $(this).html($(this).data('listhtml'));
        $(".serverList li").not(':has(.remove)').prepend('<a href="#" class="remove">&times;</a>');
    },
    start: function (event,ui) {
        $(ui.item).css('display','');
        $(this).data('listhtml', $(this).html());
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

For people with the same problem i updated the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fnmfndby/2/